# Plotting a decision boundary in LDA

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, lda

I am using the iris data and am trying to implement an LDA and QDA algorithm manually.

My goal would be to generate the plots manually as shown in the screenshot using the LDA and QDA codes I have created in python. But I have no idea how to manually build this from my code's information.

[image]
Here's what I came up with:

**Loading data:**

```
def load_data(cols, load_all=False, head=False):
    iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

    if not load_all:
        if head:
            iris = iris.head(100)
        else:
            iris = iris.tail(100)

    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    y = le.fit_transform(iris["species"])

    X = iris.drop(["species"], axis=1)

    if len(cols) > 0:
        X = X[cols]

    return X.values, y
```

**LDA - Algorithm:**

```
class LDA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y):
        target_classes = np.unique(y)
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        mean_vectors = []

        for cls in target_classes:
            mean_vectors.append(np.mean(X[y == cls], axis=0))

        if len(target_classes) < 3:
            mu1_mu2 = (mean_vectors[0] - mean_vectors[1]).reshape(1, n_features)
            B = np.dot(mu1_mu2.T, mu1_mu2)
        else:
            data_mean = np.mean(X, axis=0).reshape(1, n_features)
            B = np.zeros((n_features, n_features))
            for i, mean_vec in enumerate(mean_vectors):
                n = X[y == i].shape[0]
                mean_vec = mean_vec.reshape(1, n_features)
                mu1_mu2 = mean_vec - data_mean

                B += n * np.dot(mu1_mu2.T, mu1_mu2)

        s_matrix = []

        for cls, mean in enumerate(mean_vectors):
            Si = np.zeros((n_features, n_features))
            for row in X[y == cls]:
                t = (row - mean).reshape(1, n_features)
                Si += np.dot(t.T, t)
            s_matrix.append(Si)

        S = np.zeros((n_features, n_features))
        for s_i in s_matrix:
            S += s_i

        S_inv = np.linalg.inv(S)

        S_inv_B = S_inv.dot(B)

        eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(S_inv_B)

        idx = eig_vals.argsort()[::-1]

        eig_vals = eig_vals[idx]
        eig_vecs = eig_vecs[:, idx]

        # Compute the covariance matrix
        covariance = S / (n_samples - len(target_classes))

        return eig_vecs, covariance, mean_vectors
```

**QDA - Algorithm:**

```
class QDA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y):
        target_classes = np.unique(y)
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        mean_vectors = []

        for cls in target_classes:
            mean_vectors.append(np.mean(X[y == cls], axis=0))

        cov_matrices = []

        for cls, mean in enumerate(mean_vectors):
            Xi = X[y == cls]
            cov_matrices.append(np.cov(Xi.T))

        return mean_vectors, cov_matrices

    def predict(self, X, mean_vectors, cov_matrices):
        predictions = []
        for x in X:
            scores = []
            for mean, cov_matrix in zip(mean_vectors, cov_matrices):
                diff = x - mean
                inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix)
                score = -0.5 * diff.dot(inv_cov).dot(diff.T) - 0.5 * np.log(np.linalg.det(cov_matrix))
                scores.append(score)
            prediction = np.argmax(scores)
            predictions.append(prediction)
        return np.array(predictions)
```